# How to store different type of data depending on selected option

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm currently creating a contest system in PHP. For the database, I use MySQL.

When a users wants to make an submission, he can chose between 2 types of entry:

1. Link to a program
2. The program itself.

On my website, users can also create programs using a full coding environment I provide on the site. These programs then get stored to my database in the table `scripts`, which has the colums

- `user` (representing the user ID)
- `script_id` (representing the script ID)
- `name` (representing the name of the program)
- `script` (LongText representing the code of the program itself)

Now, if a user was up to make an submission, he can decide whether his submissionshould be a link to a program or a program he previously created on my website.

If he goes for the full program, he'll have to select one from a dropdown.

## My question is all about the server side.

When the user than clicks "Submit", a JSON formatted string containing the `type` of the submission (`0` or `1`) and the `payload` (a long string containing either the link or the `script_id`).

Now on the server side, I got these information and I want to store the user's submission.
**Now here's the actual question:**

How can I store this information so that I can easily access the submission's type and its value (either a link or a full source code)?

I do not want to save the whole sourcecode of the script once again, because the user already did that, it's stored in the table `scripts`.

I thought about something like:

```
*---------------------------------*
| submission_type |     value    |
*---------------------------------*
|        0        |   google.com |
*---------------------------------*
|        0        |   stackoverf |
*---------------------------------*
|        1        |       3      |
*---------------------------------*
|        1        |      10      |
*---------------------------------*
```

But that would be kind of messed up, because I do not want to have either a string *or* an int in the `value` column.

What do you think is the best way to store this data of unknown type?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial site nor search engine replacement. We can help, but it's **your** job to write the code in first place. **[Put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** first, then ask **with a clear explanation** and **[MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Also read **[How to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**, how to **[reward helpful answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)** and **[StackOverflow's Do and Don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937)s**.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This is by far not my first question. What did I do wrong about this question?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Also, this question is not about code. It's about database design and what's the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: If you click `close` under your question, then for me your question is fitting one of two last reasons shown there.

Answer (score 0):

In the db you only need a table `scripts` and a table `submission`.

In the PHP page when user select **"Link to a program"** you call the add submission function with:  `USER_ID, SCRIPT_ID`

But if user select **"The program itself"** first you call a function to create the script using the  *LongText representing the code of the program itself*. After that you now have a `script_id` so call the submission function as above.

Comment: "In the PHP page when user select  Link to a program you call the add submission function with: USER_ID, SCRIPT_ID"

But how can I then store the link, if I only store a script_id even though there is no script?!

Comment: Link to Program isnt a script in your db? Maybe you should provide a better example of what you have and what you need. Right now you only said what have you tried